# Multi-dimensional decision variable to handle cycles in directed graphs

Tags: graph, mathematical-optimization, shortest-path, linear-programming, cplex

I'm working with one variant of steiner tree for non-directed graphs using CPLEX.

In my solution, the graph is represented as a directed graph, and one of my desicion variables (called *Yuijv*) controls the direction of the path, so:

***Yuijv*** = 1 if edge (i,j) is used in one path from u to v in direction U->i->j->V. 
**Yuijv** = 0 else.

Here is how **Yuijv** is declared (and some aux code):

```
//structure
tuple edge {
    int i; //node
    int j; //node
}

tuple path {
    int u;
    edge e;
    int v;
}

setof(path) paths= {<i,<k,l>,j> | i,j in nodes : i!=j, <k,l> in edges: k!=l};

//decicion variable
dvar boolean Yuijv[paths];
```

But when i use it with this sintax to access the value:

```
Yuijv[u,<j,v>,v] = 0;
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Can't use type int for <u:int,a:<i:int,j:int>,v:int>.
```

Searching in the official documentation, and in this site, I can't find help for this problem, and i really apreciate some, or maybe a suggestion for re-define the implementation for this variable.

Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to assign the int value 0 to a decision variable of type boolean. Try adding a constraint to fix the value instead.

Comment: sum (<u,i> in aristas) yuijv[u,<u,i>,v] >= xi[u] + xi[v] -1;

Comment: Forget the last comment, I can not erase it.

The example I gave above, was actually invented, so i can publish it here, without explaining everything, and making it easier to read.

One of my real restrictions, which have the error it is:
_sum (<u, i> in edges) Yuijv [u, <u, i>, v]> = xi [u] + xi [v] -1;_
Where _xi_ is another variable desicion.

The CPLEX optimization stuio (ide), highlights the first _u_ in _Yuijv [u, <u, i>, v]._
And showing that suggest: "Can not use type int for <u: int, to: <i: int, j: int>, v: int>."

Thanks for the answer!